# Error in Value function approximator = ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement a Vanilla Policy gradient, which is basically a REINFORCE algorithm that uses an Advantage function. For estimating the Advantage function the Value function V(s) has to be computed. REINFORCE with just Return works but after trying to replace it with Advantage function I'm getting an error: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
Thank you for your help, if it helps, I will send you the entire code

```py
    # make action selection op (outputs int actions, sampled from policy)
    actions = tf.squeeze(tf.multinomial(logits=logits,num_samples=1), axis=1)

    #computing value function
    value_app = tf.squeeze(funct.critic_nn(obs_ph), axis=1)

    # make loss function whose gradient, for the right data, is policy gradient
    weights_ph = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32)
    adv_ph = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32)
    v_ph = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32)
    act_ph = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)

    #Loss for actor
    action_masks = tf.one_hot(act_ph, n_acts)
    log_probs = tf.reduce_sum(action_masks * tf.nn.log_softmax(logits), axis=1)
    loss = -tf.reduce_mean(adv_ph * log_probs)

    #Loss for critic
    critic_loss = tf.reduce_mean((v_ph - weights_ph)**2)

    #optimizers
    train_actor = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss)
    train_critic = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(critic_loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out. The problem was that I built the critic loss function using placeholder, which I fed with records from the Value function neural network. However, it is needed to not use the placeholder (v_ph) but to actually use real outputs from neural network. It means that you should record states from environment and in a training phase feed that records through the value function approximator and use its output to build loss function, which will be minimized.

```
critic_loss = tf.reduce_mean((value_app - weights_ph)**2)
```